# How I can I detect the file dragged over my window

Tags: c++, winapi, drag-and-drop

I have window created using win32 api. How can I detect if a file is dragged (not dropped) over my window? And how to get list of filenames. I know DragAcceptFiles/WM_DROPFILES messages but they don't register for dragging. I get the message when the user drops. So I cannot show if the dragged files can be dropped to that location or the file type is valid etc... I tried with Spy++ I am definitely getting no message, however when I check explorer windows I see that they are passing custom messages (WM_USER+210). 
I am searching for a winapi only solution.

Comment: Use the RegisterDragDrop function.

Comment: @Raymond: looks useful, I will do a search for file drop, how to get file list etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my question with the help of Raymond Chen,
Register your window as drop target.

http://www.catch22.net/tuts/drop-target

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776904(v=vs.85).aspx

and read file drop data using

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776902(v=vs.85).aspx